# Crystal Reports Graph Label

Tags: .net, charts, crystal-reports, report

I'm trying to change the [legend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skjAH.png) of a Crystal Report chart on Visual Studio.

[From what I've researched](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20316799/how-to-change-legend-text-of-a-chart-object-in-crystal-reports-10), I should be able to do that by clicking directly on the label while on Preview Mode, [but I can't do that because when I try to, the whole graph object gets selected.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MND3i.png). Clicking with the right button doesn't work either.

I'd really appreciate if someone could help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the label at property window take a look at this:

[image]

Another way is create is in formula fields right click ==> new==>Formula Name then bring this formula into formula editor window ==>enter a value like this

```
"I am " +  {namefield};
```

then use that formula name in a graph

Comment: Thank you, I didn't even think about looking there. But what I mean by "legend" is these labels here on the right: (http://i.stack.imgur.com/skjAH.png)